# Installation of python 3.6 on windows vista failure

Tags: python-3.x, windows-vista

I am unable to complete installation of python on windows vista because the launcher is unable to find the file KB2999226. Windows Vista is no longer supported by Microsoft. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually download the missing file **KB2999226** from the following Microsoft link
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49088
2. Disable the Windows update service
3. Install the downloaded file
4. Install Python 3.6
5. Enable the Windows update service